# Membrane resistance of a neuron

Tags: neuroscience, biophysics

I am about to simulate a neuron activity with the "Leaky Integrate and Fire" neuron model. But for that I need the membrane resistance. I was really looking a lot online, but I just cant find a value. Does anybody know the measured resistance value, or the value usually used in this model?

Comment: Welcome to BiologySE - thanks for your question... do you think you could give some references to the "Leaky Integrate and Fire" model to help other individuals better understand your question? Also, you may want to check out the help center for pointers on how to ask a good question...http://biology.stackexchange.com/help